# What are the threads shown in the Android Studio Application Profiler responsible for?

Tags: android-profiler

I want to profile my app but I'm not sure what every thread do. Of course I can suppose about the most "meaningful" threads role but some threads responsibility are still unclear for me. E.g. what is "crap"-thread and "Studio:socket" threads? Also what threads are deserve attention while profiling? By the way it's really strange for me that number of threads are not the same for emulator and physical devise:

Emulator, Run:
[image: Emulator, Run]

Physical device, Run
[image: Physical device, Run]

Where can I find descriptions of these threads? I had tried to Google it but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Studio:` threads are threads started by Android Studio's [JVMTI agent](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/jvmti.html#:%7E:text=The%20Java%20Virtual%20Machine%20Tool,0.), useful for capturing performance-related app data and sending them to the Android Studio profiler. If you don't want to see them or want to minimize their performance impact on your app, you can build your app with the [profileable](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#change-release-to-profileable) tag. This way the JVMTI agent won't be attached but you will lose some [profiler functionality](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#profileable-apps).

As for the `crap.coldshower` thread, it's a truncated string because Linux thread names are capped at 15 characters. The full name is likely some package name `com.xxxcrap.coldshower`, usually the main thread of an app.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But what's about `Thread-N`, `perfetto_hprof_` and another threads? Where can I found documentation about it?

Comment: `Thread-N` is likely a name created by either the Java runtime or some library your app uses. `perfetto_hprof_` is a thread created by Perfetto (perfetto.dev), a tool used by Android Studio to capture performance data. There isn't really a great way to find documentation of thread names as any app/library can name threads however they want.

Comment: Is there any way to distinguish between threads created by libraries my application uses and system ones?

Comment: If the library starts a new process then yes, because profiler only show threads in your app process. But if the library spawns threads in the same process as your app, there's no way to distinguish between them, unless you explicitly name all your threads (e.g. MyApp:thread1).